# Reading Entries From Access Database Into DataGridView Using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

For some reason when I try to read in numbers from an Access database using this code, I just get blank entries in my data grid. I can read strings in fine. Anyone know why this may be? And yes, the actual data type for the unread entries in Access is a NUMBER.

```
        string strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Employees.mdb";
        string strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employees";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int columnCount = dr.FieldCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            dgv.Columns.Add(dr.GetName(i).ToString(), dr.GetName(i).ToString());
        }

        string[] rowData = new string[columnCount];
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
            {
                if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() =="System.Int32")
                {
                    rowData[k] = dr.GetInt32(k).ToString();
                }

                if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() == "System.String")
                {
                    rowData[k] = dr.GetString(k);
                }
            }

            dgv.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try stepping through your code in the debugger so you can see what's happening. My first guess would be that your numeric fields aren't returned as `Int32`, perhaps they are floats or decimals instead.

If for some reason you can't step through it, try something like this:

```
            if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() =="System.Int32")
            {
                rowData[k] = dr.GetInt32(k).ToString();
            }
            else if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() == "System.String")
            {
                rowData[k] = dr.GetString(k);
            }
            else
            {
                rowData[k] = dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString();
            }
```

That will let you see what type of value is in the fields that didn't get displayed.

Comment: I get a bunch of System.Single data types.

Comment: Great, @Emily, Single is a type of floating point number, so you just need to check for that type and convert it properly.

Comment: You might also want to read about [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), @Emily. It's a much more powerful way of moving data from the database into your display.